# How to select variables which arent connected with each other?

Tags: sql, database, join, left-join

The exercise is:

Show for every Film and every Kino, if the Film is shown in the Kino
or not (Output: Filmtitel, Kino, Anzahl).
If the Film is shown in the Kino print out Anzahl>0, else print out
Anzahl 0.

I am missing the select to print out all Film if they arent shown in the Kino with Anzahl 0.

My code:

```
SELECT Film.Titel, Vorfuehrung.Kino,  1 AS Anzahl
FROM Film
join Vorfuehrung on Film.FID = Vorfuehrung.FILM
```

Code to create database:

```
CREATE TABLE Film 
( 
    FID     int, 
    Titel VARCHAR(255), 
    Laenge  int
); 

CREATE TABLE Vorfuehrung 
( 
    Film         int, 
    Kino         VARCHAR(255) 

); 

Create Table Kino
( 
    Name    VARCHAR(255), 
    Plaetze int, 
    Saele  int 
); 


INSERT INTO Film (FID, Titel, Laenge) VALUES (1, 'Die Nase', 90); 

INSERT INTO Film (FID, Titel, Laenge) VALUES (2, 'Die Hand', 85); 

INSERT INTO Film (FID, Titel, Laenge) VALUES (3, 'Der Arm', 120); 

INSERT INTO Film (FID, Titel, Laenge) VALUES (4, 'Das Bein', 75); 


INSERT INTO Vorfuehrung (Film, Kino) VALUES (1, 'Gloria'); 
INSERT INTO Vorfuehrung (Film, Kino) VALUES (2, 'Gloria'); 
INSERT INTO Vorfuehrung (Film, Kino) VALUES (3, 'Gloria'); 
INSERT INTO Vorfuehrung (Film, Kino) VALUES (2, 'Apollo'); 
INSERT INTO Vorfuehrung (Film, Kino) VALUES (4, 'Apollo'); 

INSERT INTO Kino (Name, Plaetze, Saele) VALUES ('Gloria', 200, 3); 
INSERT INTO Kino (Name, Plaetze, Saele) VALUES ('Apollo', 300, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

First do a cross join to get all `film` and `kino` combinations. Then left join the `vorfuehrung` on the `fid` and `name` (`kino` should probably have a surrogate key (integer) as well BTW.). Then you can `GROUP BY fid, name` and take the `count()` on any column from `vorfuehrung`. If a `film` wasn't shown in a `kino`, the column from `vorfuehrung` is `NULL` and therefore the row isn't counted.

```
SELECT f.titel,
       k.name,
       count(v.film) anzahl
       FROM film f
            CROSS JOIN kino k
            LEFT JOIN vorfuehrung v
                      ON v.film = f.fid
                         AND v.kino = k.name
       GROUP BY f.titel,
                k.name;
```

Comment: Ok, and how can i print out Anzahl 0 if the Film isnt shown in the Kino, with your code i can print out all films in every kino but the Anzahl is 1 every time?

Comment: @M.Eichhorn: Have you even tried it? Apparently not as I had a wrong column in it which had caused an error you'd complain about... As explained if the column from `vorfuehrung` is `NULL` it isn't counted. Ergo, if all are `NULL` for a `film` and `kino` it is `0`.

Comment: yeah i corrected the error and tried it then i get all Film printed out in every Kino and Anzahl is 1 every time

Comment: @M.Eichhorn: Then you'll see that the `anzahl` is `0` for example for `('Das Bein', 'Gloria')`. Here, [have a look](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=249cfdb6ca9faeff51e6b2a3a345fcd9).

Comment: How can i sent you a picture what i get printed out?

Comment: @M.Eichhorn: There's no need to. See the fiddle I linked, it works as claimed. You must have an error somewhere. Check if you used my query verbatim. I suspect you changed something.

Comment: Yeah, it worked now i tried the same code but got a different result, i dont know why. Thx for the help.

Comment: I found my fault, when i got the error i changed v.vid to f.fid and not v.film